# how to use a brew formula from github?

Tags: sqlite, homebrew

I got the following error for https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/homebrew-personal/blob/master/sqlite.rb

Is this because this formula is too old and does not support my OS version?

```
$ brew  install sorin-ionescu/homebrew-personal/sqlite
==> Tapping sorin-ionescu/personal
Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/sorin-ionescu/homebrew-personal'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 19, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (19/19), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
remote: Total 19 (delta 1), reused 6 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (19/19), done.
Error: Invalid formula: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/sorin-ionescu/homebrew-personal/dvtm.rb
dvtm: undefined method `sha1' for #<BottleSpecification:0x00007f8d5a983ef8>
Error: Invalid formula: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/sorin-ionescu/homebrew-personal/osxfuse.rb
osxfuse: unknown version :snow_leopard
Error: Invalid formula: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/sorin-ionescu/homebrew-personal/httpie.rb
httpie: Unsupported special dependency :python
Error: Invalid formula: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/sorin-ionescu/homebrew-personal/minidlna.rb
minidlna: undefined method `sha1' for #<Resource::PatchResource:0x00007f8d5a0b4250>
Error: Cannot tap sorin-ionescu/personal: invalid syntax in tap!
```

Answer (score 0):

This very custom tap is outdated. The command you used is totally right.